# Drools : Getting the catched word in a list in THEN

Tags: drools

Below is my pojo class

```
-----------------------------------pojo_Classes2.RootDoc.java-----------------------------------

package pojo_Classes2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"content",
"person"
})
public class RootDoc {

@JsonProperty("content")
private String content;
@JsonProperty("person")
private List<String> person = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("content")
public String getContent() {
return content;
}

@JsonProperty("content")
public void setContent(String content) {
this.content = content;
}

@JsonProperty("person")
public List<String> getPerson() {
return person;
}

@JsonProperty("person")
public void setPerson(List<String> person) {
this.person = person;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Here is the type of rule which i want to apply

$list1=[gaurav,gagan,anshu....]

...................................................................................................................

**Rule1**

**If**

content contains any of the above $list1

**Then**

Retrieve which name was captured in content and set person the person name in then

............................................................................................................

For eg. gaurav and gagan were captured in content then set get that gaurav and gagan were matched in content and get them back in then part.

Is it possible in drools

Comment: Your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653648/how-to-return-a-list-from-inside-of-accumulate-in-drl-drools/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but create object of your class like:
when
$rd : Rootdoc(****your query****);
then
rd.setPerson(***query***);
end